# TClientDataSet - how to 'cancel' loadfromfile?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a TClientDataSet that stores data in .cds format.

Let's say i did this :

```
clientDataSet1.loadFromFile('myclient.cds');
```

After i did this, is there a way to revert the loading and put the component in the state it was BEFORE i called this method, so i can add / delete fields that are not related to the .cds file ?

I suppose i need to use 'clearData' option , but i only can do this at design time, i did not found a way to call it in run time.

Comment: I hope the answer I've posted answers your main point.  However, please could you edit your q to explain exactly what you mean by "so i can add / delete fields that are not related to the .cds file " as the ability to do these operations seems unrelated to reverting the dataset to its state before LoadFromFile was called. Are you asking whether you can change the structure of the dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, `SaveToFile` and `LoadFromFile` exist mainly to support the CDS's
"Briefcase" mode of operation whereby you can work on a local copy of database records
while disconnected from the records' source database, save the changes locally
and then apply them once you reconnect to it. The saved file includes the change cache
of the CDS, so that you can do something like this:

```
 clientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('myclient.cds');
 clientDataSet1.UndoLastChange;
```

and that will revert the CDS's records to the state they were in prior to the
last change saved to the CDS before SaveToFile was called.

However, that is not quite what you asked, which seemed to me to be how to revert
the CDS to whatever state it was in prior to `LoadFromFile` being called, and at that
point it may have contained entirely different data.

If you want to be able to restore this prior state, you can do, **provided**
you take steps to save it before calling `LoadFromFile`.

Simplest would be

```
clientDataSet1.SaveToFile('myclient.prv');
clientDataSet1.loadFromFile('myclient.cds');

if ReloadPreviousVersion then
  clientDataSet1.loadFromFile('myclient.prv');
```

or, if you want to avoid saving to disk

```
var
  PrvData : OleVariant;
[...]
  PrvData := clientDataSet1.Data;
  clientDataSet1.loadFromFile('myclient.cds');

  if ReloadPreviousVersion then
    clientDataSet1.Data := PrvData;
```

(or you could save to/load from an in-memory stream).

Btw, I don't know whether you are familar with it, but CDSs have a [SavePoint property](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TCustomClientDataSet_SavePoint.html) which is very handy for backtracking and undoing changes; unfortunately SavePoints do not allow backtracking past operations like `LoadFromFile` and `ApplyUpdates` because these clear out the CDS's change cache.

Regarding your 'clearData' query, if you just want to clear out the CDS's data, just do

```
clientDataSet1.EmptyDataSet;
```